# What is a proper way of writing entity POCO classes in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core has a "code first mentality" by default, i.e. it is supposed to be used in a code-first manner, and even though database-first approach is supported, it is described as nothing more than reverse-engineering the existing database and creating code-first representation of it. What I mean is, the model (POCO classes) created in code "by hand" (code-first), and generated from the database (by Scaffold-DbContext command), should be identical.

Surprisingly, official EF Core docs demonstrate significant differences. Here is an example of creating the model in code: https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html And here is the example of reverse-engineering it from existing database: https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

This is the entity class in first case:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the entity class in second case:

```
public partial class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Post = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

The first example is a very simple, quite obvious POCO class. It is shown everywhere in the documentation (except for the examples generated from database). The second example though, has some additions:

- Class is declared **partial** (even though there's nowhere to be seen another **partial** definition of it).
- Navigation property is of type **ICollection< T >**, instead of just List< T >.
- Navigation property is initialized to **new HashSet< T >()** in the constructor. There is no such initialization in code-first example.
- Navigation property is declared **virtual**.
- DbSet members in a generated context class are also **virtual**.

I've tried scaffolding the model from database (latest tooling as of this writing) and it generates entities exactly as shown, so this is not an outdated documentation issue. So the official tooling generates different code, and the official documentation suggests writing different (trivial) code - without partial class, virtual members, construction initialization, etc.

My question is, trying to build the model in code, how should I write my code? I like using ICollection instead of List because it is more generic, but other than that, I'm not sure whether I need to follow docs, or MS tools? Do I need to declare them as virtual? Do I need to initialize them in a constructor? etc...

I know from the old EF times that virtual navigation properties allow lazy loading, but it is not even supported (yet) in EF Core, and I don't know of any other uses. Maybe it affects performance? Maybe tools try to generate future-proof code, so that when lazy-loading will be implemented, the POCO classes and context will be able to support it? If so, can I ditch them as I don't need lazy loading (all data querying is encapsulated in a repo)?

Shortly, please help me understand why is the difference, and which style should I use when building the model in code?

Comment: Regarding point 3, based on my own experience from a recent project... I strongly suggest not initializing them to empty collections in the constructor. The reason for this is that your business logic, in many cases, needs to be able to determine if the detail collection is empty or just hasn't been loaded yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I try to give a short answer to each point you mentioned

- `partial` classes are specially useful for tool-generated code. Suppose you want to implement a model-only derived property. For code first, you would just do it, wherever you want. For database first, the class file will be re-written if you update your model. So if you want to keep your extension code, you want to place it in a different file outside the managed model - this is where `partial` helps you to extend the class without tweaking the auto-generated code by hand.
- `ICollection` is definitely a suitable choice, even for code first. Your database probably won't support a defined order anyway without a sorting statement.
- Constructor initialization is a convenience at least... suppose you have either an empty collection database-wise or you didn't load the property at all. Without the constructor you have to handle `null` cases explicitely at arbitrary points in code. Whether you should go with `List` or `HashSet` is something I can't answer right now.
- `virtual` enables proxy creation for the database entities, which can help with two things: Lazy Loading as you already mentioned and change tracking. A proxy object can track changes to virtual properties immediately with the setter, while normal objects in the context need to be inspected on `SaveChanges`. In some cases, this might be more efficient (not generally).
- `virtual IDbSet` context entries allow easier design of testing-mockup contexts for unit tests. Other use cases might also exist.

Comment: Note, EF Core doesn't have lazy-loading (or change-tracking) proxies yet. I'm honestly not sure why RevEng is generating virtual nav props.

Comment: I've filed issue [#6326](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6326) to discuss using `virtual` with the team.

Comment: Most collections consist of unique values. For example, you won't have two identical entries in the `List<Post>` collection. The HashSet is therefore most often the semantically correct choice for representing this.

Comment: @MikeBrind Lists in database are among the few things, where I wouldn't necessarily focus on the semantic choice. Many items and heavy focus on iterative access would be a good reason to use a list. Also, if someone doesn't go with the POCO idea and starts implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, a `HashSet` wouldn't allow to first create 2 new items, add them to the collection, then set their properties, then saving the changes. Because the two items would be equal before they are initialized. Not gonna happen? You never know until you work in team with strange coding habits.

Comment: Yes - I was explaining **why** HashSet tends to be used in examples and reverse engineered code. Not necessarily espousing it as the correct choice.