# User object not set to an instance of object?

Tags: c#, database, exception, code-first

As far as I can tell, this is a pretty classic error. I've tried to understand exactly why it happens, but I don't get why it happens in my code ..
I have two classes, user:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public List<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    }
```

and organization:

```
public class Organization
    {
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    }
```

In my main program, my goal is to create a new organization with a name provided by the user. Then, I want to get a username from the user. Then, the organization first inputted should be added to this user. As far as I can tell, my main() is working on an instance of an object? Main looks like this:
                Console.Write("Enter name of organization: ");
                var orgName = Console.ReadLine();

```
            var org = new Organization{OrganizationName = orgName};
            db.Organizations.Add(org);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter username: ");
            var userName = Console.ReadLine();
            var user = new User {Username = userName};
            user.Organizations.Add(org); //I get the exception on this line
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

The exact exception is: "CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample.User.Organizations.get returned null."

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the `Organizations` property to an empty list:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public List<Organization> Organizations { get; set; } = new List<Organization>();
}
```

*The following is not recommended as it is prone to produce exactly the problem you are having:*
<strike>or:</strike>

```
var user = new User { Username = userName };
user.Organizations = new List<Organization>();
user.Organizations.Add(org);
```

Comment: Also, your edit made your answer worse. It's *recommended* to initialize all collections of EF entities in the constructor in order to avoid manually instantiating them (as your second example shows)

Comment: The reason for the downvote is my second comment. You shouldn't recommend not following best practices. There's a reason the EF scaffolder automatically generates the constructor with the instantiation of `HashSet<T>` for collections

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ok, did not know that it was officially recommended. I write my models on my own and sometimes forget to initialize lists, but normally do it exactly that way. I updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks for your input!

Comment: You are welcome. As an FYI, the recommended version is `public ICollection<T> Name { get; set; } = new HashSet<T>();`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you by any chance have some reference for that? I'm really interested in the background for that exact recommendation, because I mostly use `List<T>` in my models as they are easiest to work with in many of my use-cases and I like to avoid calling `ToList` to often...

Comment: @ChrFin I don't have an official reference at hand, but this kinds of summarizes it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954108/what-is-a-proper-way-of-writing-entity-poco-classes-in-entity-framework-core/38954731